# Trouble with starting emacs daemon using crontab's @reboot

Tags: cron, emacs

I'm trying to configure my system to start `emacs -daemon` when I start the system. So, I've added following line to my `crontab`.

```
@reboot /usr/bin/emacs -daemon
```

And then when I start my system, It seems `emacs -daemon` has executed. I can see it in `htop`:
[image]

However, when I try to attach to the emacs daemon, It says it can't find the server (as if `emacs -daemon` never ran):

```
$ emacsclient -c
emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
emacsclient: To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

        --socket-name
        --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
        --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)
```

Do you know what is happening?

/p.s. The OS in use is `archlinux`, & emacs is 28.2/

Comment: I have no issue with your steps in Ubuntu. Are you using Mac? [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148787/why-emacsclient-cant-find-socket-after-executing-emacs-daemon)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Mine is in Archlinux on Thinkpad.

Comment: Did it happen in `crontab`(without reboot) and manually run the command? Or the version [not match](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/35769/18273).

Comment: Are you using encrypted home directories? If entering your password (or otherwise passing through a normal login process) is a requirement to unlock the home directory encryption, the emacs daemon started from crontab won't have access to the encrypted home directory, and the daemon socket may land into a wrong filesystem, in a directory that will be covered up as the real home directory is mounted at login.

Comment: @林果皞, Sorry If I'm understanding your comment wrong, and answering wrongly: when manually running `emacs -daemon`, my `emacsclient` is connecting. But on system reboot / boot, `emacsclient` isn't attaching to the server started by the `cron`. And about versions, both `emacs` and `emacsclient` have same version  28.2 (there is no other version installed).

Comment: @telcoM, I'm not using an encrypted home directory. However, I'm using `startx` to start `x`. Is it possible tjhat: `cron` running `emacs -daemon` before `x` server starts, and it causing some problem? (then again, I've used emacs without x server on this machine on TTY terminal).

Comment: Use the terminal command `sudo lsof -p785` to see if your `emacs -daemon` has opened a socket, and, where the socket is. If there's no socket,  do you need `(server-start)` in your `~/.emacs`?

Comment: @Garid I mean are you able to run it on cron with specific time such as `30 14 * * *` without `@reboot` to ensure normal cron no issue. btw, you can try `@reboot emacs -daemon 2>/tmp/log2 >/tmp/log1` or `@reboot strace -f -s 1000000 emacs -daemon 2>/tmp/slog2 >/tmp/slog1` to dump the log to know what's going on.

Comment: @waltinator, `sudo lsof -p785` outputs nothing, even if I added `(server-start)` in my init file.

Comment: @waltinator, in fact `sudo lsof -p785` outputs nothing, even if I manually execute `emacs -daemon` (with emacsclient connect).

Comment: @林果皞, thanks for making great point, I just found out starting emacs daemon with `30 14 * * *`  type cron-task results same behavior as `@reboot`. I also, tried out the read up log files as you suggested, but it was identical to that of manual `emacs -daemon`.

Comment: @Garid Can you compare the output of success and failure `strace -f -e file emacsclient -c`? Are both logs able to find/stat the same socket file? Is socket name similar to `/tmp/emacs1000/server` able to access? Are the socket has the same `ls -l` output when success vs failutre?